# Data validation in macro working but throws 1004 error if a different macro is run

Tags: excel, vba

I have three macros, they all do quite a lot but the first one applies the formatting to the sheet and data. Within this macro it is supposed to apply a drop down to column 'C', with the drop downs values being dependent on what is in column 'N'. I have managed to do this with the simple formula for column 'C'..

```
=INDIRECT($N2)
```

The macro seems to work as it creates the desired result. However, when I then run one other macro in particular I get a 1004 error on the data validation line of code in the macro that appears to have already been executed. (The macro that is leading to the first one getting an error is opening a new workbook.)

Its the bottom two lines that are getting the error.

```
Range("C2:C1500").Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(" & Range("$N2").Address & " )"
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? The macro with the code getting the error runs fine, it only shows the error when one specific macro is run anytime after. However, if I step through the second macro that is triggering the first macro to error then nothing happens (no errors appear and the second macro runs fine).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your worksheet protected?

Comment: `xlBetween` can only be used if two formulas are provided for validation.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Range("N2").Address(False, True)` ?

Comment: `xlBetween` used with `xlValidateList` doesn't seem legal. Remove the `Operator` argument.